# Replace SRC attribute with TITLE in LI Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the HTML given below:

```
<ul id="thumbsPhotos">
     <li src="/images/1alvaston-hall-relaxing-lg.jpg"  onclick="updatePhoto (this.title)"><img src="/images/1alvaston-hall-relaxing-sl.jpg"  width="56" height="56"></li>
     <li onclick="updatePhoto(this.title)" src=""><img src="" width="56"  height="56"></li>
     <li onclick="updatePhoto(this.title)" src=""><img src="" width="56"  height="56"></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to replace all the `src` in `<li>` tags not in `<img>` tags using `InnerHTML`. With this, my output will be:

```
<ul id="thumbsPhotos">
     <li title="/images/1alvaston-hall-relaxing-lg.jpg"  onclick="updatePhoto(this.title)"><img src="/images/1alvaston-hall-relaxing-sl.jpg"  width="56" height="56"></li>
     <li onclick="updatePhoto(this.title)" title=""><img src="" width="56" height="56"></li>
     <li onclick="updatePhoto(this.title)" title=""><img src="" width="56" height="56"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So by clicking on the `<li>` element, you want to change the nested `<img>` src with that `<li>`'s title attribute value?

Comment: no, i think he wants to change his output so the LI's "src" attribute is now a "title" attribute.

Comment: no I have a src attribute in <li> (Please check the first html), I just want to replace all the src attributes with "title" (Please check the second html)

Comment: done server-side, right?

Comment: I don't understand why there are src tags in an <li> in the first place?

Comment: "using InnerHTML" means you want this to happen "within" the browser using javascript? And why has it to be innerHtml? ...and why is there a src attribute anyway? ;)

Comment: Editors: quick breaking the encoding of the tags!!!!

Comment: wow: there were about 4 edits within a minute of each other then... /me goes to edit it again...

Comment: What do you mean by "with innerHTML"? Some of your comments below seem contradictory and you are not explaining yourself at all.

Comment: I think this is a homework problem.

Comment: @chris-marasti-georg: Ditto. The OP is being very evasive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but here's a regex which might do it for you...

```
// find:
<li ([^>]*)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>

// replace:
<li $1title="$2"$3>
```

**Update**: tested and it works on your example.

If you wanted to run this on the client side using Javascript (for whatever whacky reason), you could do this:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("thumbsPhotos");
ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML.replace(
    /<li ([^>]*)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>/g,
    '<li $1title="$2"$3>'
);
```

Comment: can you please give this solution using innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but that is not a very semantic way to do things.  Where is this coming from?  Why is there ever a src on the li element?

Assuming you want a javascript option, you could use something like jquery to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li[src], li[src='']").each(function() {
        var li = $(this);
        li.attr("title", li.attr("src"));
        li.removeAttr("src");
    });
});
```

Comment: can it be possible with using innerHTML, using regex

Comment: In the browser?  You still need to run some sort of javascript.  Why are you closing yourself off to this solution?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: basically I need to change this "src" to "title" on page run time

Comment: Well, the code I have there will do that.  You can host the jquery library, or link to the minified version at http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js.

Then just throw the code above into a script tag.

Comment: And you still haven't answered the question of *why* you have a src attribute on the li tag?  Why not create correct HTML in the first place?

Comment: heh - my answer using plain javascript is actually less code. :)

Comment: Yes it is, and it should probably be above mine :)  Assuming the guy knows how to accept an answer, it will be.

Answer (score 0):

You could most likely use a RegEx replace that matches on the src attribute and do the conversion. I see that you want to also add the title attribute even if there is no match, that should be possible as well.

I'll try to dig up some RegEx examples for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this once wouldn't just find and replace work?

Otherwise I agree that a regex is the best option.